# How does the mainClass setting work in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I can't seem to find any details of how the `mainClass` option works in the build configuration of sbt. You specify the name of a class to use when you invoke the `run` action, but what does it actually do with it? Does it call a method on the class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/BuildConfiguration#Run_Options

> *Method mainClass is of type Option[String] and specifies an optional main class to run when the run task is invoked. The default implementation specifies no main class (None). When mainClass is not specified, the run task will determine which class to run automatically. If exactly one main class is detected, it is run. If multiple main classes are detected, the user is prompted for which one to run.*

The class name is expected to refer to an object of the same name that has a `def main(args:Array[String]): Unit` method. That method is run.

So if you create

```
package foo
object Foo { def main(args:Array[String]) { println("foo") } }
```

You can then use `override def mainClass = Some("foo.Foo")` so that the *run* target would run `foo.Foo`.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. How is a class "run"?

Comment: Edited my answer a bit. Or are you asking about sbt internals?

Comment: Nope, you got it. Thanks. Why is this not documented anywhere? Am I missing it?

Comment: Looks like it is in section 9.5 of the Scala Language Specification to me - http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf . But until now I hadn't checked since this is analogous to the ``static void main(String[] args)`` used in Java.

Comment: @huynhjl To be clear, in the case that there is exactly one `object` with the main method you describe, does SBT assume that is the main class without having this key defined?

Comment: @DeaconDesperado, yes I think so. This answer is quite old and sbt has kept evolving. I would check http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Command-Line-Reference and see if things are still the same.